# Envio de JWT sem Framework

Tags: javascript, front-end, jwt

Qual é a melhor maneira, em termos de boas práticas e praticidade, para simplificar o processo de trafegar um JWT?

Sei que com Ionic ou Angular, após configurar algum módulo para JWT, a aplicação passa a injetar o token em todas as requisições de forma automática, porém, quero fazer algo similar sem o uso deles.

Através do artigo abaixo, podemos ter a ideia de como implementar o JWT em si, porém, ele finaliza o artigo apenas com o armazenamento do token, preciso compreender como modelar a próxima etapa sem ter que ficar enviando o token manualmente em todas as requisições.

https://jonathanmh.com/example-json-web-tokens-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No [exemplo](https://jonathanmh.com/example-json-web-tokens-vanilla-javascript/) (link também inserido na pergunta), o token é gravado em um *cookie*, correto?

```
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
```

O passo seguinte é implementar um função que intercepta o *request* antes que seja enviado e que adicione o token no cabeçalho da requisição:

```
(function(send) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
        var jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if(jwtToken)
            this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + jwtToken);
        send.call(this, data);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

O que o código acima faz é verificar se existe o *cookie* identificado por *token*.

```
var jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
if(jwtToken)
//...
```

O *cookie* armazena o JWT Token. Se esse valor existir, então será injetado no *header* da requisição, normalmente no cabeçalho `Authorization`.

```
this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + jwtToken);
```

Para mais informações, poderá ler a [**documentação**](https://jwt.io/introduction), mais precisamente a secção [**How do JSON Web Tokens work?**](https://jwt.io/introduction/#how-do-json-web-tokens-work-)

Comment: Muito obrigado Filipe! Excelente, minha duvida estava no em interceptar os requests

Comment: @DavidSilva a resposta ajudou? O problema foi resolvido? Se sim, marque a resposta como certa. Obrigado.